# How do I get values when radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, label

I have three radio buttons with another input. What I want is when I click on any radio button those another input value should be display in the label tag. I try some code but It's not correct.

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('plan');  
    for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
      if(ele[i].checked)
        document.getElementById("investplan").innerHTML = document.getElementById("planinvest").value;
      }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="plan" checked onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text"value="10" id="planinvest1" class="hidden-plan-type">

<input type="radio" name="plan" onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text"value="20" id="planinvest2" class="hidden-plan-type">

<input type="radio" name="plan" onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text"value="30" id="planinvest3" class="hidden-plan-type">

<label id="investplan"></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nextElementSibling` like in `document.getElementById("investplan").innerHTML = ele[i].nextElementSibling.value;`

**Demo**

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('plan');
  for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].checked)
      document.getElementById("investplan").innerHTML = ele[i].nextElementSibling.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="plan" checked onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text" value="10" id="planinvest1" class="hidden-plan-type">

<input type="radio" name="plan" onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text" value="20" id="planinvest2" class="hidden-plan-type">

<input type="radio" name="plan" onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text" value="30" id="planinvest3" class="hidden-plan-type">

<label id="investplan"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solid way to do it. I've added labels to these element groups because it makes it easier to access the associated text element value, and also because it's good practice in forms.

I set up the event listeners in a script rather than repeat them inline for each element. Again, just good practice and keeps logic separated from content.

I've also added a way to kick it off on page load and populate that element immediately based on whatever default checked value exists.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="plan"]')].forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', displayRadioValue));

  function displayRadioValue(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      let val = e.target.closest('label').querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
      document.getElementById("investplan").innerHTML = val;
    }
  }

  //initialize

  displayRadioValue({
    target: document.querySelector('input[name="plan"]:checked')
  })
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5pc'

}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="radio" name="plan" checked />
<input type="text" value="10" id="planinvest1" class="hidden-plan-type">
</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="plan" />
<input type="text" value="20" id="planinvest2" class="hidden-plan-type">
</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="plan" />
<input type="text" value="30" id="planinvest3" class="hidden-plan-type">
</label>

<label id="investplan"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this
only if That radio buttons are fixed id's and name

```
document.getElementById("investplan").innerHTML = "Invest plan is"+document.getElementById("planinvest"+(i+1)).value;
```

here i am concatenating checkbox index +1 and getting values of planinvestX value.

Full code:

```js
    function displayRadioValue() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('plan');  
    for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
      if(ele[i].checked)
        document.getElementById("investplan").innerHTML = "Invest plan is "+document.getElementById("planinvest"+(i+1)).value;
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="plan" checked onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text" value="10" id="planinvest1" class="hidden-plan-type">

<input type="radio" name="plan" onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text" value="20" id="planinvest2" class="hidden-plan-type">

<input type="radio" name="plan" onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text" value="30" id="planinvest3" class="hidden-plan-type">

<label id="investplan"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of input by it's id dynamically

**Demo**

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
   var ele = document.getElementsByName('plan');  
for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
   let inputIndex = i+1
  if(ele[i].checked)
    document.getElementById("investplan").innerHTML = document.getElementById(`planinvest${inputIndex}`).value;
}
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="plan" checked onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text"value="10" id="planinvest1" class="hidden-plan-type">

<input type="radio" name="plan" onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text"value="20" id="planinvest2" class="hidden-plan-type">

<input type="radio" name="plan" onclick="displayRadioValue()" />
<input type="text"value="30" id="planinvest3" class="hidden-plan-type">

<label id="investplan"></label>
```